Ensure Quartz job to run at startup when using Quartz.Extensions.DependencyInjection
I am using Quartz with DI, like this:
services.AddQuartz(q =>
{
    // Create a "key" for the job
    var jobKey = new JobKey("MyJobKey");

   // Register the job with the DI container
   _ = q.AddJob<MyJobClass>(opts => opts.WithIdentity(jobKey));

   // Create a trigger for the job
   _ = q.AddTrigger(opts => opts
      .ForJob(jobKey)
      .StartNow()
      .WithIdentity("MyJob-trigger") // give the trigger a unique name
      .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
          .WithIntervalInSeconds(300)
          .RepeatForever()));
});

This job should run every 5 minutes. Additionally I want this job to ensure to run immediately at application startup.
My issue is that when I spin-up multiple instance of my service, in some cases the job DOES NOT trigger at startup.
Initially I assumed that .StartNow() is exactly what I need, but it is not. The docs of .StartNow() says:
/// Set the time the Trigger should start at to the current moment -
/// the trigger may or may not fire at this time - depending upon the
/// schedule configured for the Trigger.

How to ensure this job starts at startup?
